# How to install Windows 7 on Mac mini server?

Tags: windows, mac-mini

Previously I installed Windows 7 on a Macbook Air without problems using Boot Camp Assistant and the excellent directions [here](http://howto.cnet.com/8301-11310_39-20020513-285/install-win-7-on-macbook-air-from-a-usb-drive/).

Now I am trying to install Windows 7 on a Mac mini server and I encounter error with every approach I take. I already have a bootable USB disk with Windows 7 installer.

First I tried to install Windows 7 directly booting the installer. Installer refused to continue displaying an error mentioning something about GPT drive.

Second I tried to install using Boot Camp, but it does not exist on Mac mini servers!

So I copied the Boot Camp Assistant app from Macbook Air, and selected the option "Download the Windows Support software for this mac". It was not able to find and download anything.

I thought I could handle the driver issues later, I used Boot Camp Assistant to make the 500 GB harddisk Windows installable. Then I booted into the installer, selected BOOTCAMP partition and formatted it. Installer did not continue displaying 0x80300024        error.

I run out of ideas and am rather frustrated. Are there any simple instructions on how to install Windows 7 on Mac mini server? Or how can I solve my problem and install?

Comment: i'm trying to do this with the lion version of mac mini server.
i am having issues
i also get the error message person stated above me. If someone can help, i called apple care and the guy on the phone said that the mac mini ships with OS lion and OS lion Server, i'm a bit confused. Any input is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Boot Camp requires a $29 Snow Leopard OS X DVD (***not the server DVD***) and an external drive. The [MacBook Air SuperDrive](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MC684ZM/A?mco=MTY3ODQ5OTY) works excellently with no driver hassle.

Sorry I don't have a list of drivers and steps to make up for the work done on the OS X since I'm a wimp and will pay good money to save an hour or two my time. Apple only bundles the Windows Drivers for it's hardware with the client version of OS X (AFAIK)

I hope if someone else has done the hard work, they post their experience. The official Apple solution is simple and works well.

Comment: I am asking how to install Windows on mac mini server not MBA.

Comment: The drive was initially released and named for the Air - which was the first mac without an optical drive. The Mini Server is the second and also uses that drive to let bootcamp work.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to figure it out.  First I tried installing Windows 7 via USB thumb drive however that didn't work. So I purchased an Apple USB SuperDrive and used my Window 7 Home Premium DVD and Boot Camp Assistant to accomplish the task.

Answer (score -1):

finally I did it. all I did I run win7 installation by using DVD player not by USB. All you need is a Boot Camp, Apple's DVD player and Win7 DVD.

I did it after 6 months of trying by googling.

Comment: Could you please expand on your solution?

Comment: I bought a DVD player from apple and I already have a original Window 7 home premium. Then I start the boot camp after I formatted the 2nd hard disk (which you already have in server Mac MINI). Then I completed the installation. that's it.

Comment: Great, would you please add it to your answer? Comments can get deleted. Thanks!

Comment: I will do it soon